# Do i need my own domain to start building my website using wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, dns, web

I am a web developer. I know how to build websites from scratch using html, css, javascript etc.. but I want to give WordPress a try.

Before I start, I need to know if I can build my website without owning a domain or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends if you want your website to be online or offline. 
If you want it to be offline, you won't need a domain or a webspace. Just install XAMPP or WAMP like Diego said. 
If you want it to be online, your Wordpress files need to be uploaded on a webspace (you could also get free hosting on http://www.bplaced.net/?lang=en) and if you don't want an own domain, you could use the IP address to reach your website.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to use the XAMPP and forget everything that confuses you for now. 
You can get the detailed information here at http://wordpress.org

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't necessarily need a domain name to have a Wordpress site. Just go to http://www.wordpress.com and create a free account. You won't need any technical know-how for making and publishing the blog, it's all done for you automatically and you'll get your free sub-domain as [username].wordpress.com.